# Failed to save view with table alias

Tags: google-bigquery

Have a simple SELECT query that uses aliased table names, that runs in the web UI, but when I click Save View, and leave the same Project and Dataset names selected, and give the view a name in the Table ID field, the following error appears:

```
SELECT d.* FROM dataset.table AS d

Failed to save view. Table name cannot be resolved: project name is missing.
```

If I remove the table alias the view saves. Is this a view creation issue, or do I need to adjust my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce. Every time I try, I get the view saved.

Since the error says "project name is missing" could you add the project name to the query?

Instead of:

```
SELECT d.* FROM dataset.table AS d
```

Try:

```
SELECT d.* FROM project:dataset.table AS d
```

---

Update: This seems a bug, that you can sidestep by saving this view:

```
SELECT d.* FROM `powerful-prism-118719.dataset.table` AS d
```

Comment: `Query Failed
Error: Not found: Project sflow
Job ID: powerful-prism-118719:bquijob_49443f72_15672490b25`

Comment: Feel free to leave a job id so someone from the BigQuery team can debug this

Comment: Added IDs above. Standard SQL for project:dataset.table format?

Comment: Oh, you should have mentioned Standard SQL earlier. Now I can reproduce the bug. But I can fix it too by adding the project name as in `\`project.dataset.table\``.

Comment: This works, but it appears the project name can't be used, only the project ID? Project name is a bit easier for users.

Is this a bug I need to log, or is that already done?

Comment: Only the project id is unique - I'll strongly suggest to start a new project with an easier to use name (I don't like those auto-generated ones)

Comment: I believe this was fixed recently (and should work as expected soon) but I will follow up with one of our engineers to double check. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like some more work is needed to fix the underlying issue, so I filed https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=652 to track the problem. Thanks again for the report.